# How to query from two column of a same table where equal to one value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table as follow

```
id|  reagent1  | reagent 2
1 |  coffee    |  milk
2 |  sugar     |  coffee
3 |  coffee    |  salt
```

If I would like to get the reagents of coffee, the result should be

```
reagentofcoffee
milk
sugar
salt
```

How can I make a query to get expected result? I am new to mysql and I have tried many time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `case` :

```
select case when reagent1 = 'coffee' then reagent2 
            when reagent2 = 'coffee' then reagent1 end as reagentofcoffee
from tbl
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT IF(reagent1 = 'coffee',reagent1,reagent2) as reagent FROM table WHERE reagent1 = 'coffee' OR reagent2 = 'coffee'
```

Answer (score 0):

A `case` expression in the `select` list should do the trick:

```
SELECT CASE reagent1 WHEN 'coffee' THEN reagent2 ELSE reagent1 END
           AS reagentofcoffee
FROM   reagents
WHERE  'coffee' IN (reagent1, reagent2)
```